# COPY command postgres syntax error

Tags: sql, postgresql, limit, dump, postgresql-copy

I am trying to export from a large postgres 8.1 table a couple of rows using

```
copy (select * from tablename limit 100) to 'absolute path to file';
```

but I get

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "(" at character 6.
```

Any ideas what might be going wrong ? By the way I am not super user in the database but I believe that would have produced a different kind of error. If you have any other idea to dump a couple of rows from SQL (in a format to insert them easily, without coding) other than using copy I open to suggestions.

Comment: Please copy-and-paste the exact command you're using, including the actual table name and file name.

Comment: You are aware that 8.1 has been deprecated and de-supported for a long time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To overcome the shortcoming of version 8.1 you can create a `TEMPORARY TABLE` and use it in `COPY TO`:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE t_tmp AS
SELECT * FROM tablename LIMIT 100;

COPY t_tmp TO '/absolute/path/to/file';
```

Temp. tables are dropped at the end of a session automatically. If you want to keep the connection open you could drop the table explicitly or wrap it in a transaction which you roll back (what's already written to the file is never rolled  back.)

```
BEGIN;
CREATE ...;
COPY ...;
ROLLBACK;
```

Or you upgrade to a more recent version, which would be a very good idea in general.
[PostgreSQL 8.1 has reached end of life in Nov. 2010](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/).

Comment: Thanks that worked fine. As far as the newer version I know but as a developer I am told to keep using that.

Comment: @user1845360: You have my sympathies. ;)

Answer (score 0):

In postgresql 8.1 you cant `COPY` from `SELECT`. It was added in 8.2

Look at the differences here http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/sql-copy.html and here http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/sql-copy.html